# Laravel Framework - Difference between creating a new project via laravel or composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Been following along several Laravel tutorials online and they all create a new project through either of these two commands:

```
laravel new project-name
```

or

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name
```

They both seem to generate the same template, but are there any differences between the two one should know about? Laravel docs are unclear on this, and couldn't find an answer online, would appreciate if someone can clear it up for me.

Comment: You can check yourself by doing a recursive diff on the two directories. There should be no difference AFAIK. The source code for `laravel new project-name` is at https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name` will do two extra things as far as I know. These are executed because of `scripts` in `composer.json`

1. `cp .env.example .env`
2. `./artisan key:generate`

[composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json#L41-L46)

Comment: Andrew Hood, could you explain a little better what the #2 thing is?

Comment: @LeonardoSibela #2 generates application secret key and assigns it to app key field in your .env file created in step #1.